# How to save data from more than 3 html <input> </>

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2017

Hello I have a form with several html/input tags. Like so:

```
   <form class="form-group">
            <div class="body table-responsive">
                <table class="table m-b-0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>age</th>
                            <th>phone number</th>
                            <th>ID</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td>@item.name</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" 
                                    class="bordered">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" 
                                   class="bordered">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" 
                                    class="bordered">
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I havent named or id them yet , since I know there is a way to fill all inputs and save them all at the same time when a submit or button is pressed, I just dont know how.

Do I need to add something a tag or attribute on the  in order to be able to save all inputs at the same time when the  is pressed?

Comment: I dont need the exact line of code... with some guidence or a link where to learn would be ok

Comment: Please take a look to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4
I think this can be helpful to start.

Comment: thanks, the info looks great.. but Im looking on doing this without using generated scaffolding. And looking foward that this form works like when you are inserting data after creating a table in Mysql workbench

Comment: What will you be posting the data to on the server side?  Add more detail on the type of server-side framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign names to each input and add place a submit button. When you click submit, user input will be sent to the server with the given method.

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
    <div class="body table-responsive">
        <table class="table m-b-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>phone number</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
                    var i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="input1_@i" id="" value="" 
                            class="bordered">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="input2_@i" id="" value="" 
                           class="bordered">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="input3_@i" id="" value="" 
                            class="bordered">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Or you can listen to the submit event and handle it yourself.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // you can get the input data from 'this' (form element)
    // here comes your validation and server call
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of @i on "input1_@i" ? ... Also, do I do the same for id="" and value=="" ?

Comment: You just have to give different names to the inputs. It was just an example to mention that. Unless there are some default values, you don't need to set values for the inputs.

Comment: Ids can remain empty btw.